# Empty anonymous inner class in java

Tags: java, guava, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I was looking into [the Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and I came across an empty anonymous inner class in [`TypeToken`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained#TypeToken).

```
TypeToken<List<String>> stringListTok = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {};
```

What is exactly use of **empty anonymous inner class** and what are the useful scenarios where it can be helpful?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The purpose of this is to allow `TypeToken` to find the *superclass* of the instance - which will preserve the type argument information.

For example, although an `ArrayList<String>` object doesn't know that that its element type is `String`, due to erasure, the superclass information is *not* lost, so `new ArrayList<String>{}` knows that its superclass is `ArrayList<String>`, not just `ArrayList`. `TypeToken` uses that technique to represent a constructed generic type.

Comment: I've been using `TypeToken` for some time, but never quite appreciated the subtlety and cleverness. That is pretty awesome

Answer (score 19):

There's one use, that Guava might use. As you know, types are lost after compilation, but if the type is spefied at the class level, then it's not lost after compilation and it can be extracted by reflection. I'll put the code to extract the type in a minute.

---

Edit
I don't know if the code is of any use, but here it's

```
public class Reflect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super<String> aStringSuper = new Super<String>() {};
        aStringSuper.method();

        Super<List<Integer>> aListSuper = new Super<List<Integer>>() {};
        aListSuper.method();
    }

}

class Super<T> {

    public void method() {
        Type genericSuperclass = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass;
        for(Type type : parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()) {
            System.out.println(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats the actual use of TypeToken.